# opencl speed and OUT_OF_RESOURCES

Tags: python-3.x, opencl, pyopencl

I am very new to opencl and trying my first program. I implemented a simple sinc filtering of waveforms. The code works, however i have two questions:

1. Once I increase the size of the input matrix (numrows needs to go up to 100 000) I get (clEnqueueReadBuffer failed: OUT_OF_RESOURCES) even though matrix is relatively small (few mb). This is to some extent related to the work group size I think, but could someone elaborate how I could fix this issue ?
   Could it be driver issue ?

**UPDATE:**

- leaving groups size `None` crashes
- adjusting groups size for GPU `(1,600)` and IntelHD `(1,50)` lets me go up to some 6400 rows. However for larger size it crashes on GPU and IntelHD just freezes and does nothing ( 0% on resource monitor)

2.I have  Intel HD4600 and Nvidia K1100M GPU available, however the Intel is ~2 times  faster. I understand partially this is due to the fact that I don't need to copy my arrays to internal Intel memory different from my external GPU. However I expected marginal difference. Is this normal or should my code be better optimized to use on GPU ? **(resolved)**

Thanks for your help !!

```
    from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
    import numpy as np
    import pyopencl as cl
    import os
    os.environ['PYOPENCL_COMPILER_OUTPUT'] = '1'       
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def resample_opencl(y,key='GPU'):
            #
            # selecting to run on GPU or CPU
            #
            newlen = 1200  
            my_platform = cl.get_platforms()[0]
            device =my_platform.get_devices()[0] 

            for found_platform in cl.get_platforms():    
                if (key == 'GPU') and (found_platform.name == 'NVIDIA CUDA'):         
                    my_platform = found_platform
                    device =my_platform.get_devices()[0]
                    print("using GPU")


            #
            #Create context for GPU/CPU
            #
            ctx = cl.Context([device])

            #
            # Create queue for each kernel execution
            #
            queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx,properties=cl.command_queue_properties.PROFILING_ENABLE)
    #        queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

            prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
            __kernel void resample(      
                int M,
                __global const float *y_g,
                __global float *res_g)

            {
                int row = get_global_id(0);
                int col = get_global_id(1);
                int gs = get_global_size(1);
                __private float tmp,tmp2,x;
                __private float t;
                t = (float)(col)/2+1;


                tmp=0;
                tmp2=0;


                for (int i=0; i<M ; i++)
                    {
                    x = (float)(i+1);
                    tmp2 = (t- x)*3.14159;
                    if (t == x) {
                        tmp += y_g[row*M + i]  ;
                                    }
                    else 
                        tmp += y_g[row*M +i]  * sin(tmp2)/tmp2;
                     }

                res_g[row*gs +  col] = tmp;


            }
            """).build()

            mf = cl.mem_flags

            y_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=y)
            res = np.zeros((np.shape(y)[0],newlen)).astype(np.float32)
            res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, res.nbytes)

            M = np.array(600).astype(np.int32)
            prg.resample(queue, res.shape, (1,200),M, y_g, res_g)


            event = cl.enqueue_copy(queue, res, res_g)
            print("success")
            event.wait()
            return res,event





    if __name__ == "__main__":
        #
        # this is the number i need to increase ( up to some 100 000)
        numrows = 2000  
        Gaussian = lambda t : 10 * np.exp(-(t - 50)**2 / (2. * 2**2))


        x = np.linspace(1, 101, 600, endpoint=False).astype(np.float32)
        t = np.linspace(1, 101, 1200, endpoint=False).astype(np.float32)
        y= np.zeros(( numrows,np.size(x)))
        y[:] = Gaussian(x).astype(np.float32)
        y = y.astype(np.float32)

        res,event =  resample_opencl(y,'GPU')
        print ("OpenCl GPU profiler",(event.profile.end-event.profile.start)*1e-9)

        #
        # test plot if it worked
        #
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x,y[1,:],'+')
        plt.plot(t,res[1,:])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the issue:

- IntelHd : turning off profiling fixes everything. Can run the code without any issues.
- K1100M GPU still crashes but I suspect that this might be the timeout issue as I am using the same video card on my display.

Answer (score 2):

- **Re 1.**

Your `newlen` has to be divisible by 200 because that is what you set as local dimensions (1,200). I increased this to 9600 and that still worked fine.

***Update***

After your update I would suggest not specifying local dimensions but let implementation to decide:

```
prg.resample(queue, res.shape, None,M, y_g, res_g)
```

Also it may improve the performance if`newlen` and `numrows` were multiply of 16.

It is not a rule that Nvidia GPU must perform better than Intel GPU especially that according to Wikipedia there is not a big difference in GFLOPS between them ([549.89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units) vs [288–432](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HD_and_Iris_Graphics)). This GFLOPS comparison should be taken with grain of salt as one algorithm may be more suitable to one GPU than the other. In other words looking by this numbers you may expect one GPU to be typically faster than the other but that may vary from algorithm to algorithm.

Kernel for 100000 rows requires:

```
y_g: 100000 * 600 * 4 = 240000000 bytes =~ 229MB
res_g: 100000 * 1200 * 4 = 480000000 bytes =~ 457,8MB
```

Quadro K1100M has 2GB of global memory and that should be sufficient for processing 100000 rows. Intel HD 4600 from what I found is limited by memory in the system so I suspect that shouldn't be a problem too.

- **Re 2.**

The time is not measured correctly. Instead of measuring kernel execution time, the time of copying data back to host is being measured. So no surprise that this number is lower for CPU. To measure kernel execution time do:

```
event = prg.resample(queue, res.shape, (1,200),M, y_g, res_g)
event.wait()
print ("OpenCl GPU profiler",(event.profile.end-event.profile.start)*1e-9)
```

I don't know how to measure the whole thing including copying data back to host using OpenCL profiling events in pyopencl but using just python gives similar results:

```
start = time.time()
... #code to be measured
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: Re 1 . Increasing it to 9600 i get the same error unfortunately ... But i have updated for the problem i am interested in increasing numrows   

Re 2. Thanks for this clarification. However even with python it seems like my K1100 GPU is slower than intel HD.